# How to localize an error message on a form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is it possible in Rails 7 to localize the attributes in a form object including `ActiveModel::Model`?

I have the following

```rb
class  ProductionDataForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :monitorable_type

  validates :monitorable_type,  presence: true
end
```

And when `monitorable_type` is missing, I'd like to display `Post can't be blank` instead of `Monitorable type can't be blank`.

So, as I do for objects inheriting from `ApplicationRecord`, I tried to define

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      production_data_form:
        monitorable_type: "post"
```

But is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ActiveModel::Attributes` to declare the attribute and scope the translation keys to `activemodel` instead of `activerecord`.

```
class ProductionDataForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :monitorable_type, :string # ?
  validates :monitorable_type, presence: true
end
```

```
en:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      production_data_form:
        monitorable_type: "post"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That works just fine.